# how to push notification to all users in flutter like

Tags: android, ios, iphone, flutter, visual-studio

hello guys i want to send notification to all users in my firebase by API like this :

```
`var serverToken ="" ; 

sendNotify(String title , String body , String id) async{

await http.post(

Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'),

headers:<String,String>{'Content-Type':'application/json',
'Authorization':'key=$serverToken',},

body:jsonEncode(

  <String,dynamic>{

    'notification':<String,dynamic>{

      'body':body.toString(),

      'title':title.toString()

    },

    'priority':'high',

    'data':<String,dynamic>{

      'click_action':'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',

      'id':id.toString()},
```

//'to':'all', <<<<<<< here i want to send it to all users not by token }));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you should use topics ,

You need to subscribe users to the `all` topic and no need for tokens when sending the notification

> Based on the publish/subscribe model, FCM topic messaging allows you to send a message to multiple devices that have opted in to a particular topic. You compose topic messages as needed, and FCM handles routing and delivering the message reliably to the right devices.

```
// subscribe to topic on each app start-up
await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('all');
```

and your data

```
jsonEncode({
     'topic': "all",
    'data': {
      'via': 'FlutterFire Cloud Messaging!!!',
      'count': _messageCount.toString(),
    },
    'notification': {
      'title': 'Hello FlutterFire!',
      'body': 'This notification (#$_messageCount) was created via FCM!',
    },
  });
```

Comment: thanks alot for answer but this code make it auto ? or I need to add new user in topic everytime ?  also i got problem  here {await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('all');
} << instance give me error

Comment: Given that you need to send notification  to all users, you just have to subscribe the user on app open. `subscribe to topic on each app start-up` .  Tokens are attached to devices and need to refreshed now and then .

Eg  you can have this in your home page 

 Also do mark as answer if it helped you. Thanks